# show source code of ftp site in richTextBox

Tags: c#, ftp

I want to show the source code of a ftp site using C# in a richTextBox. In a browser it is look like

```
4/13/12 4:52:00 PM
4/13/12 4:54:00 PM
9/2/10 12:00:00 AM
4/13/12 4:46:00 PM
5/8/12 9:13:00 AM
3/7/09 12:00:00 AM
```

but when I saw this in richTextBox :

```
Apr 13 16:52
Apr 13 16:54
Sep  2  2010
Apr 13 16:46
May  8 09:13
Mar  7  2009
```

I want to show data as like it is viewed in browser.

My code :

```
string url="ftp://ftp.something.com/"
FtpWebRequest req;
req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);            
            FtpWebResponse res = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
            richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I don't know where I am wrong due to which in some lines I get Year but not time and in some get time but not year.

Comment: Is `4/13/12 4:52:00 PM ...` the _source code_? You seem to get a list of dates, you just need to parse it and print in whatever format you want.

Comment: this is a part of a source code, in this part I get problem

Comment: There's no such thing as *the source code of a ftp site*. Please describe what you're trying to get here.

Comment: in source code there is a directory name followed by date and time it is modified

Answer (score 0):

Before you send your request and get your response, you could add a method to request better/more details.  Try:

```
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
```

or

```
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
```

Comment: What are you getting for:
res.BannerMessage;

Comment: Different FTP Servers (like IIS, Apache) implement the LIST command for FTP slightly differently. Sometimes, the .BannerMessage can give you a hint about different approaches to parse the returned information. At this point, you might want to consider using a different FTP client object/library that meets your needs better. Where I work, we use Chilkat FTP, but there are some easy, free ones on codeproject.com